# Socket java disconnect

Tags: java, sockets

I made this program and i have a problem. When a client disconnect the server crashes and i don't know how to solve this problem.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.net.*;
 public class clientread extends Thread{

Socket sc;
public int ver=0;
public clientread(Socket sc)
{
    this.sc=sc;
}
public void run()
{   BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(true){
    try{
    String mes=buf.readLine();
    if(mes.equals("END"))
    {
        sc.close();
        break;
    }

    if(mes!=null)
    {
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        ps.println(mes);
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

}

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class citireserver extends Thread{
    Socket sock;

    public citireserver(Socket sr)
    {
        sock=sr;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try{
            BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String mes=buf.readLine();
            if(mes!=null)
                System.out.println(mes);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }



    }

}
```

The first one reads a message from keyboard and transmit it to the server and the server transmit it to the rest of the clients and the second one reads everything transmitted from the  server and print it. I thought to put in the first class a condition where if the client input "END" it will terminate but a don't know to end all of this.
This it the client class which access this two classes

```
     import java.net.*;
     public class client {

    public static void disc(Socket sc)
    {
        try{
        sc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        Socket sr=new Socket("192.168.0.105",1028);

            new clientread(sr).start();
            new citireserver(sr).start();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


import java.net.*;
 public class server {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("the server is running");
    try{
    ServerSocket sr=new ServerSocket(1028,100);
    while(true)
    {
        new handler(sr.accept()).start();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.net.*;
 public class handler extends Thread {
public static ArrayList<Socket> sock=new ArrayList<Socket>();
Socket sc;
public handler(Socket sc)
{
    this.sc=sc;
}
public void check()
{
    if(!sc.isConnected())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<sock.size();i++)
        if(sock.get(i)==sc)
            sock.remove(i);
    }
}
public void run()
{
    sock.add(sc);
    System.out.println("connected");
    while(true)
    {
        try{
    BufferedReader io=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
    String ms=io.readLine();
    System.out.println(ms);
    if(ms.equals("END"))
        {

        break;
        }
        if(ms!=null)
        {
            Iterator<Socket> it=sock.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                Socket vv=it.next();
                PrintStream ps=new PrintStream (vv.getOutputStream());
                ps.println(ms);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    try{

        sc.close(); 
        check();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I thought to put if in the first class after buf.readline and if the condition it true then sc.close and break. But it does nothing and i get a message probably because this socket is used in another thread in the second class and i don't know how to stop all of this. I get this error in the client which i close

> java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed    at
>   java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:876)   at
>   citireserver.run(citireserver.java:15)

Edit:After i resolved with the thread i get another

> error:java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
>       at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:916)
>       at handler.run(handler.java:41)

This error appear after i disconnect one client and i think it comes from the fact that that socket is not removed from the arraylist and when it iterate it goes on that socket.Why it doesnt remove it? what is wrong with check()?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: @user6575913 He means what errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: for the program like it is now i don't get any errors. i quit the client with ctrl+c and then the server programs runs in an infinite loop(i don't know why) and print the message "null"

Comment: as you can see i don't have the condition with "END" because i dont know where to put it. in the server i have a function that verify every socket if it disconnected and remove it from a socket ArrayList but i think i don't know how to disconnect it and from where.i tried multiple methods including socket.close but the server does the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Because you are using `while(true)`.

Comment: i tried with a condition and break but the server continues. i will put now the server too

Comment: An infinite loop is not a crash.

Comment: but it says null and then go like this for ever and if you look you will see that i check for null and i don't know why.if i implement the condition it says something with thread exception and i suspect that it comes from the second thread that use that socket.

Comment: You check for null, but you don't exit the loop or close the socket when you get it. Ergo you loop infinitely. Which is the problem. 'Says something with thread exception' is not a problem description.

Comment: i posted what does if i put the condition. and yes i dont exit the loop but i  dont display the null on screen but this program does it and i don't know from where it get null if i dont display it. and there it the problem with the thread which i posted

Comment: You say the program "crashes". I would normally expect Java to show a stack trace ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace ) to point you to the exact line in your code.

Comment: `while(true)` is a *deadlock* and makes applications crash or (even worse) hang indefinitely. Never use it. Ever. There is literally not a single use-case for it and its simply *"bad coding"* - even programs which are supposed to run forever usually have event-driven program exit routines or continuously check for internal flags ... thats what professionals learn during the first few years of their job training, even students learn it nowadays ... with exceptions, of course (bad colleges, most of the time)

Comment: maybe i misused the term 'crash'.Sorry.

Comment: ok but you know a way to solve this in the form it is now?

Comment: what is wrong with 'check()' function. after i close the socket i call this function but nothings happens. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `readLine()` returns null you should:

- stop reading
- exit the loop
- close the socket.